# How would the polar front move?

Tags: climate, geography, weather

I am in the process of working out the climate zones for a custom continent. Two of the defining features are its poleward placement in the Southern Hemisphere and the large mountain range running from the northern tip of the continent to the southern edge.

Statement 1: As the Intertropical Convergence Zone and the Polar Front both move with the seasons, the central north-south mountain range would likely affect the movement of the Polar Front.

Statement 3: This primary mountain range is quite tall, with an average elevation comparable to the Caucasus Mountains along its length (17000 feet). However, there is a 250 mile "gap" in the range where elevation drops to around 7000 to 8000 feet. Further south, there is another, much smaller "gap" where the elevation drops to around 10000 feet.

Question: Would the polar front, and the accompanying rains, switch between these two gaps depending on the season or instead remain routed through one gap year-round?

Below is a a map of the continent, with contour lines marking mountainous regions. The lines progress in roughly 4000 ft intervals, starting at around 4000 feet.
[image]

Comment: This map is incomplete. What is south of the continent? How close is it to the equator? You mention the Intertropical Convergence Zone, but are there other currents between that zone and this continent that might affect the front? How large is the planet and how much temperature difference can be expected between the equator and the poles?

Comment: The continent as a whole is roughly triangular, with the tip starting just under 20 degrees south and the base tapering out at about 80 to 85 degrees south at its maximum. The gridlines should serve as a (very) rough guide, but are not at all based on any particular projection.
Planetary characteristics are earthlike. The ITCZ rarely strays from the equator line, with the only notable atmospheric features between it and the continent being a high pressure zone centered 2-3000 miles west of the continent at around 30 degrees south.